Generic object interface with matching keys
I'm trying to make a generic interface to define a translation dictionary where the primary keys specify the language, and within each language the same keys are present.
Here's my attempt so far using generics (preferable):
interface TranslationDict<K extends string, O extends K[number]> {
  eng: Record<K, string>;
  jpn: Record<O, string>;
}

const translationDict: TranslationDict<string, string> = {
  eng: {
    year: "year",
    month: "month",
    day: "day",
    file: "file",
  },
  jpn: {
    year: "年",
    month: "月",
    day: "日",
    file: "ファイル",
    file2: "bla", // I want this to throw a type error
  },
};

Without generics, this works, but seems like way too much boilerplate:
const cols = ["year", "month", "day", "file"] as const;

export const commonCols: {
  eng: Record<(typeof cols)[number], string>;
  jpn: Record<(typeof cols)[number], string>;
} = {
  eng: {
    year: "year",
    month: "month",
    day: "day",
    file: "file",
  },
  jpn: {
    year: "年",
    month: "月",
    day: "日",
    file: "ファイル",
    file2: "bla", // TYPE ERROR
  },
};

How do I use generics to constrain the keys of jpn to be the same as the keys of eng?

You could use a helper function to aid with inference, as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

That's super clever - I have never seen the use of a helper function. The NoInfer might not be necessary. It seems to work without it, but please explain its use if you can. Go ahead and post your answer!

Without NoInfer you will see the error somewhere else, probably. I will post an answer soon.

You do want to use a generic type like TranslationDict<K>:
interface TranslationDict<K extends string> {
    eng: Record<K, string>,
    jpn: Record<K, string>
}    

but then when you annotate the type, you need to write out the type argument manually:
const dict: TranslationDict<"year" | "month" | "day" | "file"> = {
    eng: {
        year: "year",
        month: "month",
        day: "day",
        file: "file",
    },
    jpn: {
        year: "年",
        month: "月",
        day: "日",
        file: "ファイル",
        file2: "bla", // error!
        //~~~ <-- Object literal may only specify known properties
        // but 'file2' does not exist in type 
        // 'Record<"year" | "month" | "day" | "file", string>'
    },
};

This gives you the excess property error you want, but it's redundant because you're forced to write "year" | "month" | "day" | "file" yourself. You really want the compiler to infer that from eng, perhaps like
// don't write this, not valid
const dict: TranslationDict<infer> = { ⋯ };

but that's not currently supported. You can't infer a type argument for a generic type. There's a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#32794, but until and unless that's implemented you need another approach.

The most common way of getting behavior like this is to write a generic function to help. TypeScript does infer generic type arguments when you call a generic function, so we can use that inference instead. The helper function is just an identity like d => d at runtime. Its only purpose is to aid with inference.
Like this:
const translationDict = <K extends string>(
    d: TranslationDict<K>) => d;

And then instead of annotating, you call the function:
const dict = translationDict({
    eng: { // error!
        year: "year",
        month: "month",
        day: "day",
        file: "file",
    },
    jpn: {
        year: "年",
        month: "月",
        day: "日",
        file: "ファイル",
        file2: "bla",
    },
});

That works, but the error isn't where you wanted it to be.  The compiler ends up inferring K as "year" | "month" | "day" | "file" | "file2" and then complains about eng being wrong.  Maybe that suffices for your needs.
But if you want the compiler to only infer K from eng and then just check K against jpn, you could use the NoInfer utility type to block inference from the utterance of K in the jpn property.  That is, change TranslationDict<K> to
interface TranslationDict<K extends string> {
    eng: Record<K, string>,
    jpn: Record<NoInfer<K>, string>
}    

And once you do this, you finally get the desired behavior as specified:
const dict = translationDict({
    eng: {
        year: "year",
        month: "month",
        day: "day",
        file: "file",
    },
    jpn: {
        year: "年",
        month: "月",
        day: "日",
        file: "ファイル",
        file2: "bla", // error!
        //~~~ <-- Object literal may only specify known properties
        // but 'file2' does not exist in type 
        // 'Record<"year" | "month" | "day" | "file", string>'
    },
});

Now K is inferred as "year" | "month" | "day" | "file" and thus the object literal's eng property is fine, but jpn has an excess file2 property.
Playground link to code
